# Overriding MacOS High Sierra /usr/lib (or how to static link)

Tags: static-libraries, static-linking, macos-high-sierra

I have a program I'm compiling that requires a new version of Curl. Mac default Curl is in /usr/bin and /usr/lib. I have compiled a newer version of curl and compiled using:

```
gcc mypgm.c -I ./curl-7.58.0/include/curl -I ./cJSON-master -L ./cJSON-master/build ./libcjson.1.7.1.dylib ./libcurl.4.dylib -o mypgm
```

When I run mypgm I get the error:

```
Incompatible library version: mypgm requires version 10.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

Running `otool` I found that the libcurl in my build dir is correct, but it seems to be wanting to use the /usr/lib version, which can't be deleted (without disable SIP, delete, reenable, which I don't want to do in case some future version reinstalls).

So my question is two-fold.

1. I want to know if it is possible like with `$PATH` to change the way macOS finds libraries (I read something about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` being ignored), and
2. How should I redo the `gcc` line to static link those libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after coping the libraries into the /usr/local/lib folder.

```
gcc -I ./curl-7.58.0/include/curl -I ./cJSON-master /usr/local/lib/libcjson.1.7.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib mypgm.c -o mypgm
```

I think the relative path (./) for the libraries rather then absolute path is the key.